# How to use less <= and >= in materlized view table in cassandra

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, cassandra, cql

My CQL query

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_test AS 
SELECT *  FROM host_accounts WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND creation_ts IS NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (id, creation_ts) WITH clustering ORDER BY (creation_ts DESC);
```

this my query but it's gave this error `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"` when i am using this query  `select *  from mv_test where  creation_ts > 1606761000 AND creation_ts < 1609353000`;

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior of Cassandra because your query is restricted only by the condition on `creation_ts` that is the clustering column.  And because you don't have restriction on the `id` field, Cassandra don't know the partition key, and to fulfill the condition it will need to go through all data and apply filter.  And by default, Cassandra don't allow such behavior without `ALLOW FILTERING` - the same as if you have such condition on the "normal" table.

If you want to perform such query in your system, you need to change approach:

- Change data model, so data will be partitioned by date/part of timestamp, and then you need to issue multiple queries to cover all necessary time ranges
- Use Spark or custom code that will perform correct scanning of all data.  But this won't be fast because you'll need to process a lot of data.

Comment: Can you please help me that how to i change my query.. using this way

Comment: it's not the simple query change - you need to change data model, and then change queries and application code.  For data modeling, I recommend to grab freely available book on Cassandra: https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide